# Laravel 10 unable to get protected property from extended Controller

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I'm getting some error to retrieve protected property from Extended Controller.

I have this scenario :

//ItemController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Item;


class ItemController extends Controller
{
    protected $modelClassName = Item::class;
    
    protected $searchAttributes = [
        'serial',
        'model',
        'label',
        'label_supplier'
    ];

}
```

//Controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Item;
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, ValidatesRequests, DispatchesJobs;

    protected $searchAttributes = [];
    protected $modelClassName = '';

    public function getItem(Request $request)
    {
        $result = [
            'success' => true,
            'data' => null,
            'errors' => []
        ];

        try{
            $search = $request->get('search');
            $query = $this->modelClassName::query();
            if($search){
                foreach($this->searchAttributes as $searchAttribute){
                    $query->orWhere($searchAttribute, 'LIKE', $search . '%');
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception $e) {
            $result['success'] = false;
            $result['errors'][] = $e->getMessage();
        }

        $reslt['data'] = $query->get();
        
        return new JsonResponse();
    }
}
```

When I try to call function getItem(), i get error, Class not found, same with searchAttributes no loop into foreach, empty array comes from ItemController.
Many thanks

Comment: There's no code that actually uses your protected properties here. Also does `App\Models\Item` exist?

Comment: I made a mistake, now code is correct. Check it please

Comment: Could try `$search = call_user_func($this->modelClassName. '::query');` . There's probably other ways too but `modelClassName` is a string so it's trickier to use it as a class

Comment: I'm using this method with my other Laravel 9.0 Application

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not to use class initialisers but rather initialise the values in the constructor. That way you will have more control over values:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Item;


class ItemController extends Controller
{
     public function __construct() {
         parent::__construct();
         $this->$modelClassName = Item::class;     
         $this->$searchAttributes = [
            'serial',
            'model',
            'label',
            'label_supplier'
        ];
    }
}
```

also I suggest making your controller abstract (it just makes more sense I think):

```
abstract class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, ValidatesRequests, DispatchesJobs;

    protected $searchAttributes;
    protected $modelClassName;

    public function getItem(Request $request)
    {
        $result = [
            'success' => true,
            'data' => null,
            'errors' => []
        ];

        try{
            $search = $request->get('search');
            $query = $this->modelClassName::query();
            if($search){
                foreach($this->searchAttributes as $searchAttribute){
                    $query->orWhere($searchAttribute, 'LIKE', $search . '%');
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception $e) {
            $result['success'] = false;
            $result['errors'][] = $e->getMessage();
        }

        $reslt['data'] = $query->get();
        
        return new JsonResponse();
    }
}
```

This will ensure that when you do `(new ItemController)->getItem()` the correct class name is used

Comment: Where should I use (new ItemController)->getItem() in which part of my application?

Comment: That's an example. You're using Laravel so you should not need to manually initialise controllers just declare them in your routes e.g. `Route::get('item', [ ItemController::class, 'getItem' ])` or something like that